# SQL Selecting Most Recent Date (W/ Three Table Join)

Tags: sql, max, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

Using the Below SQL Query I am attempting to retrieve the most recent sessions date from Interactive_Sessions.Sessiondate while also displaying information from two other tables (Interactive.Users & Patroninfo) by using join

Something that would like this

```
JDOE     Jane     DOE    1234     janedoe@jane.com     10/27/14 10:24
JDOA     Jane     DOA    1345     Janedoe@jana.com     11/13/17 12:34
```

Below is what I am currently working with an am ensure of how to resolve the errors I am getting when attempting to execute. Is these something I am missing with the MAX?

```
Select 
        INTERACTIVE_USERS.USERID, PATRONINFO.FIRSTNAME, PATRONINFO.LASTNAME, 
        PATRONINFO.PATRONID, INTERACTIVE_USERS.EMAIL, 
        MAX(INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE)
FROM 
        INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS
JOIN 
        INTERACTIVE_USERS
ON 
        INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS.USERID = INTERACTIVE_USERS.USERID
JOIN 
        PATRONINFO
ON 
        INTERACTIVE_USERS.PID = PATRONINFO.PATRONID
GROUP 
        BY INTERACTIVE_USERS.USERID, PATRONINFO.FIRSTNAME, PATRONINFO.LASTNAME, PATRONINFO.PATRONID, INTERACTIVE_USERS.EMAIL
ORDER BY 
        MAX(INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE)
```

My problem is that when I leave in a group by statement I receive the ORA-00904 error for invalid identifier, but I have verified the table names match exactly.

When I remove the Group by statement I get the ORA-00937 not a single-group group function which I would normally resolve with a Group BY

Has anyone out there experienced something similar? Is there any tricks to resolving this kind of error or am I being dense and missed something obvious?

Alternatively I have tried this but it comes up only with the most recent Interactive_Sessions.Sessiondate for ANY Interactive_Users.Userid instead of each Interactive_Users.Userid

```
Select 
     INTERACTIVE_USERS.USERID, PATRONINFO.FIRSTNAME, PATRONINFO.LASTNAME, 
     PATRONINFO.PATRONID, INTERACTIVE_USERS.EMAIL, 
     INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE
FROM 
     INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS
JOIN 
     INTERACTIVE_USERS
ON
     INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS.USERID = INTERACTIVE_USERS.USERID
JOIN 
     PATRONINFO
ON
     INTERACTIVE_USERS.PID = PATRONINFO.PATRONID
WHERE 
    interactive_sessions.sessiondate=(Select 
    MAX(Interactive_sessions.sessiondate) from Interactive_sessions)
```

Comment: I would try removing all of your `GROUP BY` elements and see if it will run. Take elements out, and when you have something that's working, add them back in one by one.

Comment: Which dbms?  It's useless if we post answer to the wrong dbms.

Comment: What's wrong with your first query?  It seems ok.  Have you tried to run it without the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Like others I see no issue with the first query, but the second is attempting doing exactly what you asked it to `(Select 
    MAX(Interactive_sessions.sessiondate) from Interactive_sessions)` **returns a single value**, so you will only get results that match that single max(sessiondate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reducing the sessions table to just one row per userid and derive the wanted date in that process. This means introducing a subquery where you curently have a simple join. Below there is one option that employs `ROW_NUMBER()` to supply the value 1 to the "latest" date (by ordering in descending order).

```
SELECT
      INTERACTIVE_USERS.USERID
    , PATRONINFO.FIRSTNAME
    , PATRONINFO.LASTNAME
    , PATRONINFO.PATRONID
    , INTERACTIVE_USERS.EMAIL
    , IESSIONS.SESSIONDATE
FROM INTERACTIVE_USERS
JOIN PATRONINFO ON INTERACTIVE_USERS.PID = PATRONINFO.PATRONID
JOIN (
      SELECT USERID, SESSIONDATE
            , row_number() over(partition by USERID, order by SESSIONDATE DESC) rn
      FROM INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS
      ) ISESSIONS ON INTERACTIVE_USERS.USERID = ISESSIONS.USERID
                 AND ISESSIONS.RN = 1
ORDER BY IESSIONS.SESSIONDATE
;
```

Or, use a `GROUP BY` in the subquery instead (this is a more traditional approach):

```
SELECT
      INTERACTIVE_USERS.USERID
    , PATRONINFO.FIRSTNAME
    , PATRONINFO.LASTNAME
    , PATRONINFO.PATRONID
    , INTERACTIVE_USERS.EMAIL
    , IESSIONS.SESSIONDATE
FROM INTERACTIVE_USERS
JOIN PATRONINFO ON INTERACTIVE_USERS.PID = PATRONINFO.PATRONID
JOIN (
      SELECT USERID, MAX(SESSIONDATE) SESSIONDATE
      FROM INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS
      GROUP BY USERID
      ) ISESSIONS ON INTERACTIVE_USERS.USERID = ISESSIONS.USERID
ORDER BY IESSIONS.SESSIONDATE
;
```

The second approach is sufficient for your current query but it is useful to know both approaches. Using the GROUP BY approach (for example) you could also get the number of sessions using COUNT(*) which you could not do in the row_number() approach. However if you needed more columns from the sessions table that are on the same row as the "latest date" then the row_number() approach enables that.

Regarding the ORA-00904 related query. If you use a column alias like this `MAX(INTERACTIVE_SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE) AS MAX_SESS_DT` then you can use that column alias in the order clause: `ORDER BY MAX_SESS_DT`